# What is the probability of getting at least 17 out of 60 questions correct in a multiple choice test whereby 1 of 4 answers are correct?

Tags: probability

Maths isn’t my specialty and I’ve tried to search for a method to do it myself or find an automated probability calculator but I’ve had no luck.

I’d love to know the formula so that I can learn it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The number of correct answers $X$ is distributed like a binomial distribution with $n=60$ and $p = \frac14$.

You are interested in $P(X \ge 17) = 1 - P(X \le 16)$ and you can find tables online for those probabilities, or just compute the sum

$$1- \sum_{i=0}^{16}\binom{60}{i} (\frac{1}{4})^i (\frac{3}{4})^{60-i}$$

using a computer algebra system.

Using [this online calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx) (Google is your friend), I found that $P(X \ge 17)$ equals $0.32036397072$, so a 32% chance.